# How to hide unnecessary columns in the GridControl?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

Winform has 2 grids. I display related tables from the SQL Server database to them.

Here is the code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionSIPiT"].ConnectionString;

string command = "SELECT UserID, UserName,Login, idArm FROM Users";
string command2 = "SELECT id, name FROM arm";

sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command2, sqlConnection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command, sqlConnection);

DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset1, "arm");
adapter1.Fill(dataset1, "Users");

DataColumn keyColumn = dataset1.Tables[0].Columns[0];
DataColumn foreignKeyColumn = dataset1.Tables[1].Columns[3];
dataset1.Relations.Add("armUsers", keyColumn, foreignKeyColumn);

bindingSource1.DataSource = dataset1;
bindingSource1.DataMember = "arm";

bindingSource2.DataSource = bindingSource1;
bindingSource2.DataMember = "armUsers";

gridControl1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
gridControl2.DataSource = bindingSource2;
```

Please help me figure out how to hide unnecessary columns in the GridControl. Such as Id) Can the DataTable be used? If possible an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the DataSource for both grids, you can set the Visible property for the Id column to false.

Assuming the DefaultView is a GridView, the following code should do the job.

```
(gridControl1.DefaultView as GridView).Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
```